# How to manage Rails 2.3.x i18n locales programatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I would like to know if there is a way to insert, alter and remove i18n locale keys programatically (I guess I could use the DB, but I like Rails i18n and want to stay as close to it as possible).

Basically I want to know if there's a way (native, gem, plugin, whatever) to do things like:

```
I18n.add_locale_key("en", "application.messages.submit_message", "Submit message!")
I18n.add_locale_key("es", "application.messages.submit_message", "Enviar mensaje!")

I18n.remove_locale_key("en", "application.messages.submit_message")
I18n.remove_locale_key("es", "application.messages.submit_message")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As packaged, the Rails I18n API only support defining locale terms via the local .yaml or .rb files. Short of dynamically editing those files at runtime, your best bet is to use the DB functionality of a gem gem like [FastGetText](https://github.com/grosser/fast_gettext).

You could also roll your own solution, of course, but the DB method will likely work for your use case and will result in a smaller time investment.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

```
>> I18n.backend.store_translations :en, :hello_world => "Hello, world."
=> {:hello_world=>"Hello, world."}
>> I18n.t :hello_world
=> "Hello, world."
```

Comment: This method does not persist the new translations leading to translation loss upon rails restart.